# Using Embeddings API in Azure OpenAI

Tags: c#, azure-openai, openaiembeddings

When I use embeddings with Azure OpenAI I am getting 404 (resource not found):

```
    EmbeddingsOptions embdOptions = new EmbeddingsOptions(text);
    Azure.AI.OpenAI.Embeddings response = Task.Run(() => mOpenAiClient.GetEmbeddingsAsync(mWebSvc.AzureOpenAI.DeploymentID, embdOptions)).Result;
```

The text is the input text to be used to create the vector. Also, mWebSvc.AzureOpenAI.DeploymentID is a Deployment ID or Deployment Name, which is "ada2" - this is how I named the text-embedding-ada-002 model.
Also, while I created mOpenAiClient I used the URL:

```
"https://AzureOpenAIExperiment.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/ada2/embeddings?api-version=2023-05-15"
```

Any ideas? Microsoft is quite silent on these things and no documentation is provided in Azure OpenAI part of Azure SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the URL that I used before, although correct for normal HttpClient calls is not what Azure Open AI API is expecting.
It expects this:

```
https://{resourceName}.openai.azure.com
```

Where {resourceName} is a placeholder - it is the name of the resource you created on Azure. The Type Of Resource is: "Azure OpenAI". This is the resource that you deployed the model (in my case text-embedding-ada-002 that I named "ada2". This "ada2" goes as a parameter into GetEmbeddingsAsync function.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Deployment Id, if 'ada2' is correct. You can sure, verify by sending a GET request to the URL:

> https://AzureOpenAIExperiment.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments?api-version=2023-05-15

[image]

After, include the ID in your URL

[https://AzureOpenAIExperiment.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/{{ID}}/embeddings?api-version=2023-05-15](https://AzureOpenAIExperiment.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/%7B%7BID%7D%7D/embeddings?api-version=2023-05-15)

**My test**

My ID = text-embedding-ada-002

https://estudoopenai.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/text-embedding-ada-002/embeddings?api-version=2023-05-15

```
{    
    "input":"test"
}
```

[image]